# Kafka consumer missing messages while consuming messages in loop

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, talend

I am running my consumer code in loop due to memory constraints,  committing my data and then loading into tables

Following is the code which will run in loop

```
// here is the main part of the component,
// a piece of code executed in the row
// loop
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
System.out.println("Consumer created");
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));
System.out.println("Subscribed to topic " + topic);
try {
    while (pollFlag) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(context.consumer_polltime);
     if (records.isEmpty()) {
     globalMap.put("emptyRecordsFlag",false); //Passing the flag value to previous component to end loop
            break;
        }
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
            listPayload.add(record.value()); // Adding the messages to list
            i++;
            if(i>=msgbtch)
            {
                pollFlag = false; // Assigning flag value to end the poll at 5000 messages
                break;
            }       
        }
    }
globalMap.put("ConsumerObj",consumer);  
            
}   catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Consuming Msg: " + e);
            // TODO: handle exception
            //consumer.close();
    }
row3.payload= String.valueOf(listPayload); // Passing the message data to next component
System.out.println("Committing");
consumer.commitSync();
System.out.println("Closing");
consumer.close();
```

But due to some reason I seem to be missing few messages. I believe this has to do something with consumer rebalancing/Committing.

How can I check if my consumer is ready to consume the next batch of messages from the start without missing any messages?

Comment: Are there other consumers with the same group id? Are you sure the producer actually did send the messages you're looking for?

Comment: I myself pushed 5000 messages in the topic and ran my application. But table got loaded with only 4917 messages in batch mode whereas 5000 messages are loaded when loaded in one go.

Comment: Again, how did you verify all 5000 messages arrived successfully to the topic?

Comment: I checked it in control center. It shows 5000 messages lagging behind. I was able to figure out the issue myself. I just removed the break in the below if condition 
```if(i>=msgbtch)
            {
                pollFlag = false; // Assigning flag value to end the poll at 5000 messages
                break;
            }
```
The above break was breaking the for loop even before all the messages in records were loaded to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update :**
I was able to figure out the issue myself. The messages are already downloaded in the records and while looping as I have put the following condition

```
if(i>=msgbtch)
            {
                pollFlag = false; // Assigning flag value to end the poll at 5000 messages
                break;
            }
```

Even before placing all the messages in list the loop is breaking and all the messages from records is not being inserted in the list. I have removed the break condition and it's working fine